# Random(staticSeed).Next() alternative that will never change implementation and is guaranteed consistent through versions

Tags: c#, .net, random

I'm looking for something similar like:

```
new Random(staticSeed).Next()
```

but where I'm assured that the implementation will always be consistent through different .NET framework versions.

I'm specifically looking for something that:

> ...produces a sequence of numbers that meet certain statistical
>   requirements for randomness.

...to quote the comment at the `System.Random` class.

- Is there something like that in .NET or do I have to roll my own?
- is there any specific recommended algorithm nowadays?

It's not used for security.

Comment: Maybe this gives you some ideas: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx

Comment: And I'm actually not sure what you are asking for. `new Random(staticSeed).Next()` (when I understand `staticSeed` as a constant value) will always return the _same_ number, as it's the first _pseudo_-random number from the sequence initialised by that seed.

Comment: Hi Rene, I might need to clarify my question. That is exactly the behaviour that I'm looking for - a random **looking** sequence that I can regenerate forever. Think i.e. of a random generator for gamelevels, where you can keep the whole state by just saving the initial seed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is an addendum to usr's answer]

Here's a C# implementation of an XorShift RNG, ported from [this C code](http://xorshift.di.unimi.it/xorshift1024star.c):

```
public sealed class XorShiftRng: Random
{
    public XorShiftRng(ulong seed1, ulong seed2)
    {
        if (seed1 == 0 && seed2 == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("seed1 and seed 2 cannot both be zero.");

        s[0] = seed1;
        s[1] = seed2;
    }

    public XorShiftRng()
    {
        var bytes = Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray();

        s[0] = BitConverter.ToUInt64(bytes, 0);
        s[1] = BitConverter.ToUInt64(bytes, 8);
    }

    public ulong NextUlong()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            ulong s0 = s[p];
            ulong s1 = s[p = (p + 1) & 15];
            s1 ^= s1 << 31;
            s[p] = s1 ^ s0 ^ (s1 >> 11) ^ (s0 >> 30);
            return s[p]*1181783497276652981;
        }
    }

    public long NextLong(long maxValue)
    {
        return (int)NextLong(0, maxValue);
    }

    public long NextLong(long minValue, long maxValue)
    {
        if (minValue > maxValue)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(minValue), "minValue cannot exceed maxValue");

        if (minValue == maxValue)
            return minValue;

        return (int) (NextUlong() / ((double)ulong.MaxValue / (maxValue - minValue)) + minValue);
    }

    public override int Next()
    {
        return (int) NextLong(0, int.MaxValue + 1L);
    }

    public override int Next(int maxValue)
    {
        return (int) NextLong(0, maxValue + 1L);
    }

    public override int Next(int minValue, int maxValue)
    {
        return (int) NextLong(minValue, maxValue);
    }

    public override void NextBytes(byte[] buffer)
    {
        if (buffer == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(buffer));

        int remaining = buffer.Length;                                 

        while (remaining > 0)
        {
            var next = BitConverter.GetBytes(NextUlong());
            int n = Math.Min(next.Length, remaining);

            Array.Copy(next, 0, buffer, buffer.Length-remaining, n);
            remaining -= n;
        }
    }

    public override double NextDouble()
    {
        return NextUlong() / (ulong.MaxValue + 1.0);
    }

    readonly ulong[] s = new ulong[16];
    int p;
}
```

It has a long period of 2^1024 − 1, and gives very good random numbers.

See http://xorshift.di.unimi.it/ for more details.

[EDIT] Updated class to implement `class System.Random`

Comment: The Mersenne Twister is actually quite a bad algorithm. It's quality is not very good, it is slow and it has a ton of state (1.7KB!). I think it's an anti-pattern.

Comment: @usr https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister It's comparatively slow, but it's definitely not an "anti-pattern". It's main advantage for applications such as deck shuffling is it's extremely long period. It's also commonly used in numerical applications such as MATLAB (where it is the default RNG).

Comment: I understand it's being used everywhere but it shouldn't if Wikipedia can be trusted. XorShift+ or XorShift* are easy variants (twice as slow) that pass all popular randomness tests. It seems to me that XorShift(+/*) is better in each and every regard, sometimes significantly so. I'm not fond of RNGs based on math tricks in general. The linear congruential is another one of these super popular garbage generators.

Comment: @usr OK, I'll see if I can update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Great answer, thanks guys.

Comment: Just one question btw, do you happen to know what happens if I add a constructor with only one seed in it? And set the other one on 0. Is that an anti pattern? Reason is that I have only one final seed out of my parent method atm. That means that I anyway have to deduce one seed to two, by some calculation.

Comment: @DirkBoer I think it should work - it's only a problem if both seeds are set to zero.

Comment: hmm in theory I could also put it on an arbitrary number like (prime number) 7919 - that would solve that problem.. might just be a bit weird :)

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing in .NET like that. You probably should copy the code for a RNG from the web. I recommend using the Xor-Shift algorithm. It has very high quality, is super fast and easy to implement (5 lines I think).

Subjective note: It should have been the algorithm that the framework uses. The existing algorithm appears to be quite inferior.

Comment: Do you want to copy the code for XorShift from my answer into your answer, so I can delete my answer?

Comment: @MatthewWatson I think it's alright like this.

Answer (score 2):

A built in way to get a seeded random sequence without rolling your own implementation of a known algorithm is use the [Rfc2898DeriveBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx129kfs(v=vs.110).aspx) class. Pass in your seed as the `password`, use some fixed or recorded `salt`, and pass in 1 for `iterations` because you are not needing the security of multiple iterations.

This will give you a unlimited number of bytes from the [`GetBytes(int)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.getbytes(v=vs.110).aspx) call which will return the same sequence every single time for the same initial `password`, `salt`, and `itterations` values and will not change across .NET versions.