# How to reduce small array garbage?

Tags: c#, arrays, garbage-collection, garbage

I'm trying to reduce the amount of garbage generated by some algorithms that require small arrays to work efficiently. Also, using references in value types will decrease memory locality. Inlining the memory of the fixed array into a struct would improve cache efficiency.

The main goal is to keep the implementation readable, but to not generate any garbage by allocating an array.

I came up with a pattern that involves emulating an array with a struct, that trades garbage production with runtime performance:

`ulong[] smallArray = new ulong[2]`

becomes

```
struct ulong2
{
    ulong l0;
    ulong l1;

    public ulong this[ulong n]
    {
        get
        {
            return (n == 0) ? l0 : l1;
        }

        set
        {
            if (n == 0)
            {
                l0 = value;
            }
            else
            {
                l1 = value;
            }
        }
    }
}

ulong2 smallArray = new ulong2();
```

You'll need to refactor algorithms a little bit to cope with the by-value semantics instead of the original array by-ref, but otherwise, its a pretty good drop-in-and-forget replacement when you know the fixed size of the array.

How can this be optimized to keep O(1) read/write charactaristics of a linear array? Can it be optimized [without using](http://content.atalasoft.com/h/i/58208059-improving-performance-through-stack-allocation-net-memory-management-part-2) [unsafe code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/fixed-size-buffers)? Are there other approaches?

Comment: Is the generated garbage proving to be a problem in your code? What issues is it giving you? In most cases, it's fine to do managed heap allocations (very cheap) whenever you need them, and let the GC take care of the garbage.

Comment: This seems like an unnecessary optimisation - especially if you're using it to speed up a Mersenne Twister instead of using [an XOR-shift RNG](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36331735/106159)!

Comment: Have you measured the performance-impact on this optimization? I doubt it is as big as you think, array-access should be really fast.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I actually don't have hard numbers on the impact of performance, but alone from looking at it ( O(log n), lots of branches vs. O(1) without branching) it will have an impact. I don't say I am unhappy with the performance, but also looking for more elegant ways to solve the problem, especially when the arrays are fixed-size with like 8 or 16 elements.

Comment: @Baldrick Garbage is a problem because it causes the collector to kick in more often, which is a problem in realtime applications.

Comment: @MatthewWatson You're right, the MT implementation in general may not be the most optimized. But the same problem applies to e.g. fixed arrays used by structures, when you have many instances of those structures being passed around / stored with short lifetimes. Pooling may be a solution there but it still involves more overhead both for management and code readability.

Comment: Instead of long-time searching for some nano-seconds of optimization consider on your *real* problems. I bet even *if* you could make your algorithm for that particular scenario become O(1) I you probably gain just some milliseconds for your complete use-case whilst overlooking the greater issues - which might be database-access, network-load - that *really* have an impact on your overtime performance. In other words: ["premature optimization is the root of all evil" (Donald Knuth).](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization)

Comment: @HimBromBeere Yes, of course you will have to do so in any real-world application. I'd like to concentrate here on this specific issue to see if there is any C#/CLI magic that I miss that would make the solution more straightforward, like in native languages, where you could just calculate the pointer offset and fetch the memory from there. Which, in C#, without using unsafe code or allocating garbage, isn't possible (like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664785(v=vs.71).aspx).